# Ionic token based authentication

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

**SERVICES.JS**

```
app.service('AuthService', function ($q, $http) {

    var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY ='';
    var username ='';
    var isAuthenticated = false;
    var authToken;

    function loadUserCredentials() {
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
        if (token) {
            useCredentials(token);
        }
    }

    function storeUserCredentials(response) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY, response.meta.token);
        useCredentials(response);
    }

    function useCredentials(response) {
        username = response.data.username;
        console.log(username);
        isAuthenticated = true;
        authToken = response.meta.token;
        console.log(authToken);
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.meta.token;
    }

    function destroyUserCredentials() {
        authToken = undefined;
        username = '';
        isAuthenticated = false;
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + undefined;
        window.localStorage.removeItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
    }

    var login = function (email, password) {

        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

            var params = {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }

            $http({   *****// this POST METHORD IS NOT***** 
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://107.170.112.247/brain/public/api/v1/login",
                data: params,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                print : function(){
                    console.log(params);
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                // console.log(response);
                storeUserCredentials(response);
                if (isAuthenticated)
                    resolve('Login success.');
                else
                    reject('Login Failed.');
            })
        });
    };

    var logout = function () {
        destroyUserCredentials();
    };

    loadUserCredentials();

    return {
        login: login,
        //logout: logout,
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            return isAuthenticated;
        },
    };
})

    .factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS) {
            return {
                responseError: function (response) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast({
                        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
                        403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized
                    }[response.status], response);
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        })

        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
        });
```

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function(data) {
        AuthService.login(data.email, data.password).then(function() {
            console.log("kartik khandelwal");
            $state.go('/home-menu', {}, {reload: true});
            console.log("k");
        }, function(err) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Please check whether the flow is correct or not?

And my post request method is not executing !

And for every user name and password it is showing:

> UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS 401 ERROR!

and while checking the username and password the problem is it is not going into correct format to API...

Comment: I think .. u passing api data as json then try to use header  Content-Type: application/json,   if ur api not support this content type then u have to write small method to encodeURIComponent to parameter. U can try  params  = $.param(params ); angular method convert object to param before passing to http.

Comment: Not working in that way too :(